# Creating duplicate relationships from JSON data

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create relationships from JSON data by matching existing nodes in a database. Specifically, I have people nodes in a neo4j instance, and I have a dataset that corresponds to their job. I want to add a relationship from people nodes to job nodes.

The JSON data looks like this:

```
{"id": "1", "name": "Picasso", "job": {"raw": "Painter"}}
{"id": "2", "name": "Beyonce", "job": {"raw": "Singer"}}
{"id": "3", "name": "Derek Jeter", "job": {"raw": "Baseball Player"}}
```

My cypher query:

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file:/example.txt') YIELD value AS q 
MATCH (p:Person {id:q.id})
WITH q, p
UNWIND q.job as job
WITH DISTINCT p, job
MERGE (j:Job {name: job.raw})
MERGE (p)-[:WORKS_AT_JOB]->(j)
```

However, for some Person nodes I am getting duplicate relationships. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: query appear to be fine. what neo4j version do you use? and maybe you could provide JSON dataset on which you have issue ?

Comment: To be clear, does "duplicate" mean that a `p` and `j` node pair is connected by multiple  `WORKS_AT_JOB` relationships?

Comment: I am using version 3.5. The query creates duplicate job nodes and creates a single `WORKS_AT_JOB` relationship to both job nodes